# <h:commandLink> action not invoke if include with <ui:include>

Tags: google-app-engine, jsf, richfaces

If I place  inside an include file, the action will not call back bean.

Main File:

```
<h:form id="ifLogin">
    <h:panelGrid
        rendered="#{userSession.isLogin}"
        columns="2" columnClasses="columnAlignLeft, columnAlignRight"
        border="0" cellpadding="0">

        <ui:include src="\test.xhtml" />        

    ...

    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

Include file (test.xhtml)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

    <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="4"> 
        <h:graphicImage value="#{msg.urlImageHome}"
            style="height:26px;width:26px;" />
        <f:subview>             
            <h:commandLink value="#{msg.home}" style="font-size: small;" immediate="true" 
                action="#{pageNavigationBean.updateCeaAppName}">
                <f:param name="requestName" value="CEA_MAIN_PAGE" />
                <f:param name="ceaAppName" value="" />      
            </h:commandLink>    
        </f:subview>
    </h:panelGrid>  
</ui:composition>
```

The workaround is take out include file, directly place the  code to main file as below:

Main file (without using include)

```
<h:form id="ifLogin">
    <h:panelGrid
        rendered="#{userSession.isLogin}"
        columns="2" columnClasses="columnAlignLeft, columnAlignRight"
        border="0" cellpadding="0">


        <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="4"> 
            <h:graphicImage value="#{msg.urlImageHome}"
                style="height:26px;width:26px;" />
            <f:subview>             
                <h:commandLink value="#{msg.home}" style="font-size: small;" immediate="true" 
                    action="#{pageNavigationBean.updateCeaAppName}">
                    <f:param name="requestName" value="CEA_MAIN_PAGE" />
                    <f:param name="ceaAppName" value="" />      
                </h:commandLink>    
            </f:subview>
        </h:panelGrid>          

    ...

    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
```

I use richface 4.3.1  Odd is this problem not happen when I run from local GAE.  After deploy online to GAE, problem occour (i.e if using include then  action will not trigger.

Is that a bug in jsf? or richface implementation or GAE?  Any help?

Comment: There are unescaped xml characters. Not sure why behavior is different with ui:include and inlining. Anyways try escaping >>> with &gt;&gt;&gt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem identify

It is not cause by using `<ui:include>`

The problem came out when the include file is dynamic generate from back bean, for example:

```
<ui:include src="#{pageNavigationBean.appDropDownMenuUrl}" />
```

If explicit mention the url, it work, for example:

```
<ui:include src="\test.xhtml" />
```

Well, if running from my local GAE, both way are working but when deploy online, I need use explicit location instead generate from bean.  May be that is due to GAE problem where state is save at Client side (javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD).

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem with exactly the same included code (test.xhtml), but here are some recommendation:

1. Escape '>' characters (replace `>>>` by `&gt;&gt;&gt;`)
2. Specify `id` attribute for `f:subview` (it is required according to tld)
3. Change backslash ('\') to slash ('/'). So inclusion would be `<ui:include src="/test.xhtml" />`

Comment: Sorry for that >>>, I just add in for debug.  include file is display the problem is the action bean is not invoke when commandLink is click if I use include.

Comment: @songjing Try fixing points 2 and 3. As I mentioned - your test.xhtml works fine for me when included (using forward slash). If it does not for you - provide full content of main file to reproduce the issue.